# How do I translate this SQL query to Django?

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I have an SQL query in `PostgreSQL` that I'd like to translate to Django.

```
select * from main_document 
where id in (
    select distinct on (document_id) document_id 
    from main_tokenindex 
    where token in('token1', 'token2')
    order by document_id, relevance desc
) LIMIT 100
```

I have 2 tables: Document and TokenIndex. 1 to many relationship, a token can be in many documents.

I have this so far:

```
terms = []
ids = [doc.document_id for doc in TokenIndex.objects.filter(token__in = terms).
      distinct('document__id').order_by("-relevance")]

list(Document.objects.filter(pk__in=ids))[:max_res]
```

As you can see, the problem is that I'm going to the database to get the list of ids, and then going back again to get the documents. This is inefficient because I might be dealing with millions of document ids, whereas I'm only interested in a small subset (defined by the `max_res` variable, and `LIMIT` in the SQL.

How do I translate the SQL query to Django? I want the Django's query to be like the one I wrote by hand in the sense that it only returns 100 documents for example and not 1.000.000 document ids and then 100 documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = Document.objects.filter(pk__in=(TokenIndex.objects.filter(token__in=terms).distinct('document').order_by('document', '-relevance').values_list('document', flat=True)[:max_res]))
```

If you don't want 1.000.000 document ids, just return 100, you need `LIMIT` in inner query, not in outer query.

Anyway, I think if you even use `LIMIT` with outer query it will still translate to the SQL you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that doesn't help me. In the SQL query, it returns 100 documents. I cannot limit the inner query I need all the IDS and then get the documents. Is it possible to write raw sql with django?

Comment: @Ali Why do you need all the ids if you need only 100 documents? As I see your don't do any additional ordering in outer query, so what the point of limit here (and not in inner one)? And try to move slicing in my answer to outer query, I think it will get you what you need (while I still don't understand why).

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't make any sense to get all those ids when I only need 100 documents.

Quick edit: How do I print the query generated by Django?

Comment: @Ali You need 100 documents = you need 100 ids of them. So you need limit to inner query.

Comment: Could someone explain `(token__in=terms)`.  Am I right to understand that `terms = [ ]` is an empty list?  If so, how can an filter on an empty List provide a result?